# Better approach to render Svelte components from CMS driven HTML markup

Tags: javascript, html, svelte

I have the following scenario.

The CMS returns the markup to the browser in this format, where we need to render Svelte components in their respective placeholders.

- `class="component"` is the placeholder the component to render
- `name="Header"` is the name of the component
- `props="{}"` props passed to the component

```html
<div class="component" name="Header" props="{...}"></div>

<div>Some other content, not a component</div>

<div class="component" name="Accordion">
  <div class="component" name="AccordionItem" props="{...}">
    <p>Accordion item 1 body</p>
  </div>
  <div class="component" name="AccordionItem" props="{...}">
    <p>Accordion item 2 body</p>
  </div>
  <div class="component" name="AccordionItem" props="{...}">
    <p>Accordion item 3 body</p>
  </div>
  <div class="component" name="AccordionItem" props="{...}">
    <p>Accordion item 4 body</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="component" name="Footer" props="{..}"></div>
```

Parent components like `Accordion` must be able to control its child components.

Here is my progress so far:
https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-wu-oey2k?file=/public/index.html:430-1321

Looking for help and suggestions for a better way to implement it.

Thank you!

Comment: I would probably build the svelte components as [custom elements/web components](https://svelte.dev/docs#Custom_element_API) and then use the custom elements tag instead of a div.

Comment: @2pha good suggestion, thank you! 
I am wondering how will parent components in nested components like the `Accordion` in the above example have access to its child components?